# Invert non-zero submatrix in numpy, returning a matrix of original shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix, with some rows and columns equal to zero, so it is not invertible.
I need to get an iverse of non-zero submatrix, so that the inverse then has the same structure as the original matrix.
Expected behavior would be something like this:

```
>>>test
array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 4]])
>>>get_nonzero(test)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>>np.linalg.inv(nonzero)
array([[-2. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.5, -0.5]])
>>>restore_shape(inv_matrix)
array([[-2. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.5,  0. ,  0. , -0.5]])
```

Perhaps it is relevant that I originally get `test` matrix by zeroing rows and columns of some original matrix with all elements being non-zero with boolean indexing like:

```
>>>bool_index
array([False,  True,  True, False])
>>>original[bool_index, :] = 0
>>>original[:, bool_index] = 0
>>>original
array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 4]])
```

I achieved getting non-zero submatrix from original matrix by first converting it to pandas `DataFrame` and indexing with boolean arrays with `.loc` like this:

```
>>>pd.DataFrame(original).loc[~bool_index, ~bool_index].values
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

However, I am not sure, how can I efficiently restore inverted array to the original shape.

Comment: You could use `np.linalg.pinv(test)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks, that's what I was looking for, works just great! Would've accepted this as the answer, if it weren't a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To use the function formatting you propose, and assuming your input matrix can lead to a N*N matrix, the following works:

```
import numpy as np

def get_nonzero(t1):
    t2 = t1[t1 != 0]
    size = int(np.sqrt(len(t2)))

    return t2.reshape(size, size)

def restore_shape(t1, t3):

    t4 = np.zeros(t1.shape)
    idx_non_zeros = np.nonzero(t1)

    for i, elt in enumerate(t3.flatten()):
        t4[idx_non_zeros[0][i], idx_non_zeros[1][i]] = elt

    return t4

t1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
               [0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0],
               [3, 0, 0, 4]])

t2 = get_nonzero(t1)
t3 = np.linalg.inv(t2)
t4 = restore_shape(t1, t3)
```

But as proposed in the comments, `np.linalg.pinv(t1)` is much more elegant and efficient.